# Granger causality in time series

Tags: granger-causality

Granger causality uses the notion of VAR models where we can create two models one using the prediction of X alone and another using X and Y. If X,Y model performs better we can say that X causes Y. At many web resources, there is a mention of F-score and p-value to determine Granger causality. Where do they fit in with VAR models for determining Granger causality

Comment: "we can say that X _Granger-_ causes Y."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question... Consider a VAR model for ($x,y$). You test joint zero restrictions on all lags of $x$ in the equation of $y$ to find whether $x$ Granger-causes $y$. The test is an $F$-test, and the test statistic has an associated $p$-value. If the $p$-value is low enough, you reject the null hypothesis of noncausality in favour of causality. Is anything missing here?

Comment: what do you mean by join zero resrictions? Can you please clarify

Comment: You set the coefficients on lags of $x$ to zero -- that is what I mean by zero restrictions.